# Using Scanner to read an object from a file

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, file-handling

Am trying to read an object from a text file using scanner, but my problem is i cannot access the object's elements. Meaning i have stored an username and a password in the object and i want to check it with another username and password which the user will provide at run time.

Here is what i have done :

```
 //writing object to the file using printwriter 
    public void createLogin(String username,String password){

        libraryLogin_class logins=new libraryLogin_class(username,password);

        try{
            PrintWriter write=new PrintWriter("login.txt");
            write.print(logins);

           write.close();

        }catch(Exception e){}

    }
```

//This method is not fully implemented am currently stuck at this method

```
     public void checkLogin(String userName,String password)throws FileNotFoundException{

       File read=new File("login.txt");

       Scanner readFile=new Scanner(read);
     String loginObject;


      while(readFile.hasNext()){

          loginObject=(readFile.nextLine());

      //not implemented

      }


//class which creates an object with the default username and password

   public void login(){

        String username="shehan";
        String password="123";

        createLogin_class user=new createLogin_class();

        user.createLogin(username, password); //calls the creatLogin method and pass   the parameters

    }
```

So now my problem is how do i use the loginObject to check whether the object's username is equal to the username which the user provides?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Do i need to serialize to read the object's elements ? I have the get and set methods declared all ready  in the libraryLogin_class.

Comment: @boxed__l It's not a Java serialization problem. It is a general Serialization problem. The link is to a wiki. How is his object serialized in the `txt` file? Separated by `,`, `|`, etc.

Comment: It looks like a serialization issue to me, at least conceptually.  It doesn't appear to be using Java's Serialization stuff (maybe part of the problem?)  Shehan, do you have tostring() method defined for your login class?  You'll also need a deserialization method (i.e. a method that takes in a string and parses it to rebuild the login object).  Alternatively, Java can help you with this, albeit via a slightly different tack.  This is a good tutorial http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_serialization.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `PrintWriter` has a `print(Object)` method as such

```
public void print(Object obj) {
    write(String.valueOf(obj));
}
```

So calling

```
write.print(logins);
```

will write the value of `logins.toString()` to your text file. You need to control that format. So if your `toString()` method is

```
public String toString() {
    return username + "," + password;
}
```

assuming you have fields `username` and `password`, you should read it as

```
while(readFile.hasNext()){
    libraryLogin_class login = new libraryLogin_class();

    loginObject = readFile.nextLine();
    String[] values = loginObject.split(",");
    login.setUsername(values[0]);
    login.setPassword(values[1]);
    // use login
}
```

You would obviously want to validate what you're reading first.

Comment: Thanks i also tried using serialize and it worked. Thanks for helping :)